# How can a picture of a virus be taken when they are not even 300 nm (wavelength of blue light) long?

Tags: visible-light, wavelength, biology, microscopy, nanoscience

We cannot take photos of protons because they are not at least the size of the wavelength that registers into visible light. I see photos of Coronavirus in the news everywhere where there is a clear distinctive gray ball with red petal shown in such great details. How is that photo taken? Is that just an artistic impression or a real photo?

Comment: We use electron microscopes instead as they have a much higher resolution

Comment: @SandeepKumarDash That picture may be structurally correct but cannot be in true colors correct?

Comment: Yeah the colours are arbritary

Comment: Re, "true" colors. As you said, a virus particle is smaller than any visible light wavelength. There is no _true_ color. There is no color at all. The very idea of color is meaningless at that scale.

Comment: @SolomonSlow - Superman with his x-ray vision is very disappointed in you!

Comment: @JonCuster, 's funny. Just last night I was involved in a discussion about the impossibility of us imagining how critters that have different numbers of color receptors in their eyes perceive the world. Didn't think to mention Kryptonians...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pictures like this can be taken with an *electron microscope*, where the effective wavelength of the illuminating beam is far shorter than that of visible light. Those pictures are in black & white only (electrons don't have "color") but are then color-coded with tools like photoshop to highlight particular structures on their surfaces.

Furthermore, once the exact structure of the protein molecules that form the virus has been figured out, molecular biologists can then apply computer models to the protein structures and determine with great accuracy how they fold together and interlock to create a complete virus particle.

Those modeled structures can then be color-coded as well, again in the interest of highlighting where the different protein molecules are located and how they project out from the surface of the protein.

The pictures you see of ball-shaped virus particles with lumpy, colored knobs studding their surfaces were prepared in this way.